# Too much Recursion calling a method of the same name

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code snippet...

```
 this.destroy = function () {
    var grid= $("#gridObject").data("uiMyGrid");
    grid.destroy();
 }
```

When i call .destroy() on the parent object it seems to be going into a recursive loop. (Too much recursion).

I debugged a while and notice it is calling itself rather than the grid objects destroy method? How can i make it call the grid destroy?

I am sure i am missing something here.. What is it?

Comment: Presumably `grid.destroy()` and `this.destroy()` are one of the same, hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: What kind of object is `this`? Is `grid` an instance of the same object?

Comment: Actually this is slickgrid code for an editor. The this.destroy is in the editor object and the grid.destroy() is a second grid object. In the debugger they are two different objects. It would be hard to make an example of this... Let me see

Comment: Lee's comment led me to find the solution. Really this was a stupid question. The destroy on the grid was actually calling the destroy on the editor object.